# access to protected enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a base class written in VB.net that I am using it in my C# project. This base class has some properties that I have to give them value in my project. I have problem with accessing one of these properties. as Follows:

This in base class:

```
Public MustInherit Class FTPUploaderBase
{

 Private _protocol As FTPProtocol

  Protected Property Protocol() As FTPProtocol
    Get
        Return _protocol
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As FTPProtocol)
        _protocol = Value
    End Set
End Property



 Protected Enum FTPProtocol
    FTP = 1 'Standard FTP (port 21)
    SFTP = 2 'Secure FTP over SSH (port 22)
    FTPS = 3 'Secure FTP over Implicit SSL (port 990)
    FTPES = 4 'Secure FTP over Explicit SSL (port 21 - to forward to 443)
End Enum

 }
```

This is My C# class that drived from that base class:

```
 public class FTPUploadeClass:FTPUploader.FTPUploaderBase
{

 public FTPProtocol Protocol
  {
      get
      {
          return base.Protocol;
      }

      set
      {  
          base.Protocol = value;
      }

  }
    }
```

it shows this error on Protocol:
Inconsistent accessibility: Property type'FTPUPloaded.FTPUplodedBase.FTPProtocol' is less accessible than property 'My base class name here'

Solution: 
I have changed the name of the Property in my C# class and it works

Comment: Why is the enum nested inside the class to begin with?  Generally enums should be defined at the top level, unless there's a compelling reason not to do so (i.e. they are only ever used inside of one class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare a `public` property with the type `FTPProtocol` because the type itself is not visible to any class which is not inheriting from the base class.

To make it work change the visibility of the enum to `public` or create a second enum which maps to the first one ( but is `public )`.

Comment: To make your property work add `new` to it. Otherwise change the name of the property.

Comment: I have changed the name of the Property and it works Thanks Felix.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why the enum is `protected`?

Just make `FTPProtocol` enum `public`

Also, the property in the derived class should not be named the same as the base class. So rename the property in the C# derived class to anything but `Protocol`.

Comment: I made changes on the Protected Enum FTPProtocol to public Enum FTPProtocol. Not I get this error: 'My base class name here' hides inherited member 'MY C# classs name here'. Use the new Keyword if hiding was intended.